# double to string error

Tags: java, string, double

I am just learning Java and am doing a project on making a bank but i can not get it to work the  aim is for it to return the current bank balance and account number but it says double can not be returned as a string...

```
public String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe(double desiredBalance) {
    desiredBalance = 88;
    String str = "";
    double num = 200;
    String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe = String.valueOf(listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe);
    if (bankAccounts.size() <= 0) {
        str = "enter ammount to find number of years of constant saving will give 200 euro";
        for (BankAccount ba : bankAccounts) {
            str += ba.getAccNumber();
            str += ba.getBalance();
        }
        return str;
    } else {
        return (double) (num * 100);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else condition is returning (double)(num * 100). You need to return a String.

Try the code below, you need to convert the double value to a String:

```
public String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe(double desiredBalance) {
    desiredBalance = 88;
    String str = "";
    double num = 200;
    if (bankAccounts.size() <= 0) {
        str = "enter ammount to find number of years of constant saving will give 200 euro";
        for (BankAccount ba: bankAccounts) {
            str += ba.getAccNumber();
            str += ba.getBalance();
        }
    } else {
        str = String.valueOf(num * 100);
    }
    return str;
}
```

I don't normally get in the habit of doing peoples work for them, but I had a little bit of free time this afternoon:

```
    public String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe(double desiredBalance) {
        String str = "";
        double amountOfIncreasePerYear = 50; // You need to replace this...
        for (BankAccount ba: bankAccounts) {
            String currentBalance = ba.getBalance();
            if(Double.parseDouble(currentBalance) <= desiredBalance)
            {
                double numberOfYears = (desiredBalance - Double.parseDouble(currentBalance)) / amountOfIncreasePerYear;
                String currentAccNumber = ba.getAccNumber();
                str += String.Format(
                    "Account#: %s, Current Balance: %.2f, Number of Years to Reach %.2f: %f \r\n",
                    currentAccNumber, currentBalance, desiredBalance, numberOfYears
                    );
            }
        }
        if(str == "") {
            str = "No Bank Accounts";
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Keep in mind, I just typed this out in notepad so you may have to check that it compiles. Also you need to determine the value that should be in the amountOfIncreasePerYear variable. What determines that value. Is it something you can get from a BankAccount class member?

Comment: im not sure what you mean when i try that an error pops up saying it cant convert

Comment: Why don't you return str(num*100)?

Comment: i tried the new code but its said that the listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe variabl;e may not be inialised

Comment: Try it now. I don't know why you had it the way you did with:
String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe = String.valueOf(listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe);
But that was probably your problem right there.

Comment: it says the listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe may not inialise

Comment: that appears to have fixed it but thew code below is not compilingnow im sorry im new to this and dont really know what im doing

Comment: @wildcard String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe = String.valueOf(listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe); <--  this is ur problem mate, not quite sure what you want to do here

Comment: ok i want my code to always return to me the current balance and account number and the number of years it will take for equal deposites to make 200 and if the orginal deposite = 0 then return a message saying add a number greater than 0 i know there was something very wrong with the code to begin with and am someone can help

Comment: You should really have smaller more specific functions as a matter of good coding practice. Have a single function that does your calculation and call it only when you meet the proper criteria. Don't try to cram a bunch of conflicting functionality into one function.

Comment: @gmiley its part of a project and the spec says to make one method with it all in there i think i see what you mean by what you said and it makes sense but i dont think i canm do that

Comment: this is bthe way i recieved the question: String listProjectedPortfolioTimeframe (double desiredBalance)
Construct and return a String that will, for each bank account in the ArrayList, identify the:
 bank account number
 current balance
 number of years it will take for the account to reach the desired balance (passed as a
parameter).
The returned String should not include the bank accounts whose balance is already above
the desired balance.
If there are no bank accounts in the ArrayList, return the String “No Bank Accounts”.

Comment: Also a few other things I noticed. 1) you are hard coding the value of your parameter to 88, no matter what is passed in it is getting reset to 88 every time. 2) you are checking bankAccounts.size() <= 0 and then trying to iterate through it, I think you mean to check bankAccounts.size() > 0.

Comment: thanks i did not see that now the problem is with:  return (double) (num * 100);   Its saying incompatabnle types

Comment: I rewrote your function as best I could according to your specs, but you have missing information: what is the amount of increase per year to calculate how many years it takes to reach desired amount? I would suggest you not just attempt to use my code, but understand what I did and incorporate that into yours. I do not know how all of your code fits together.

Comment: @gimley may i ask where did you learn to code or know of any good sites i canm learn from?

Comment: Self-taught mostly, started back in the 90's as a teenager with various books and the internets. Plus, almost 20 years of work experience.